# Android: how to develop  plugin like feed.nu in WordPress ?

Tags: android, wordpress, apk

The feed.nu plugin generates APK(Android) file from our blog that we can use on android

I am planning to write a wordpress plugin that converts our blog into an APK file that we can install in our Android device or emulator . I am completely new to Android , but I have done a wordpress plugin previously . This feed.nu is a plugin that works in the same way . I just learned how to run an APK file in an Android emulator . So, how can i write such a plugin ? Where should i start ? Do i need to learn how Android apps are developed . Can you tell me in short how can i write my plugin  .

Will provide more details if necessary .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of feed.nu and found this question by googeling myself :)

To answer your question with an short answear...
A. Yes, you need to learn android development
B. Wordpress with php is not enough for compiling an android app. Feed.nu is using external build servers to compile the app.

I'm working on some other project witch does almost the dame thing. 
Send me an pm if your are intrested to be a part of it :)