# Android - Where should I add my files (html files like index.html) after creating project

Tags: android

I am  using command line (ant) to create and build android projects .
I created project using

```
android create project --name YourTestProject --path /home/testfolder --target android-3 --package com.company.testproject --activity MainActivity
```

Above command created a project directory "testfolder" and placed all necessary files inside it . Now, where should I add my files into that . For example , If I have "index.html" file, where should I place that . So, when I open my app on Android emulator, that index.html file should be exewcuted  . Will provide more details if necessary .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files should go into the assets folder. They are used by your app directly and are not touched by the android framework

In contrast images, styles, layouts etc for your app belong in the res folder. They are treated and managed by android.

Comment: I just added index.html with small html content , but when i opened app in emulator , it didnt show my index.html content, it is showing the default welcome msg "Hello World , <name> "

Comment: You need to embed a WebView into your app to display your html file. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: ok thanks ! Marked as answer, if possible plz answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149538/android-how-to-develop-plugin-like-feed-nu-in-wordpress .